# The separation axioms, or "how tightly a closed subset can be wrapped in an open set"

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I was looking around to understand better the separation axioms, when I found this sentence [in the wolfram page concerning the separation axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeparationAxioms.html).

[talking about the the separation axioms...]

> ...each of them tells us how tightly a closed subset can be wrapped in
>   an open set. The measure of tightness is the extent to which this
>   envelope can separate the subset from other subsets.

This looks very interesting but I don't really understand it. What does it mean when applied to T0, T1, T2, T3, T4?

Comment: I don't think this statement (at least the first part) can be applied to $T_0$. Maybe it can be used from $T_1$, because this sais that you always can wrap the closure of a point $x$ by an open set not containing some other given point $y$.

Comment: You may dismiss that comment because in topological spaces, nothing ls measured.  Among other things it gets rid of that epsilon-delta tedium.

Answer (score 3):

$T_1$: A closed set that contains just one point can be wrapped in an open set that separates it from any one other prescribed point.

$T_2$: A closed set that contains just one point can be wrapped in an open set that separates it from a whole little neighborhood of any one other prescribed point.

$T_3$: Any closed set $C$ (not necessarily just a single point) can be wrapped in an open set that separates it from some neighborhood of any one other prescribed point not in $C$.  Equivalently, any closed set that contains just one point $p$ can be wrapped in an open set that separates it from some neighborhood of any closed set that doesn't contain $p$.

$T_4$: Any closed set $C$ (not necessarily just a single point) can be wrapped in an open set that separates it from some neighborhood of any closed set disjoint from $C$.

Comment: Are these characterizations of T1, T2, T3, T4? (I.e. are these equivalent to being T1, T2, T3, T4?)

Comment: Yes, these are just the definitions of $T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4$ written using the words "wrapped" and "separates".

Comment: And what about $T_0$?

Comment: For $T_0$, see the comment from Dog_69 under the question. Of course $T_0$ is equivalent to "Given any two distinct points, at least one of them can be wrapped in an open set that separates it from the other point." But that's not exactly of the desired form.